# Instantiate new model using AngularJS, ES6 and Typescript without the use of Factories

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, domain-driven-design

I'm searching for a factory pattern that can I implement using ES6, Typescript, and AngularJS that will be compatible with Angular (v2+)?

I'm preparing our legacy AngularJS application for conversion to Angular (v2+). Part of this process involves removing the use of AngularJS factories for the instantiation of new objects and replacing them with services. AngularJS services cannot return constructor functions for initializing objects.

I have a rich javascript model that I need to create new instances of as the application is navigated. This model will contain references to angular services used to retrieve data. I need to ensure that I'm not re-using the same singleton object generated from a service.

I'm relatively new on ES6 and Typescript. In the old AngularJS way I'd use a factory to create a new object:

[image: AngularJS Factory approach]

Converting to Angular using ES6 and Typescript, **without using factory**:

[image]

I'm hopeful that I'm missing something simple and obvious related to ES6 imports to create the new object, but the AngularJS dependency injection throws me through a loop. I need to have AngularJS dependencies injected into my model, and also have new instances of that model.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Plenty of great examples of creating a rich domain object in AngularJS can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iz9zBWrhZUg

Comment: In addition, the author specifically states: "I strongly recommend to never inject anything but other models or filters in your models, otherwise you will end up with circular dependencies and all hell breaks loose." 
https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/angular-model-objects-with-javascript-classes-2e6a067c73bc